# React Hook Form "isValid" is always false when testing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, react-hook-form

I make registration modal screen and when submitting isValid value is checked.

In local environment (started by npm start), this isValid value has no problem.
But during unit test by jest, isValid value is always false even though validation rule is satisfied and no error is detected in errors variable.

So I would like to ask why.

TeamUpdateModal.tsx

```
import React, { FC } from "react";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "../../../../redux/hooks";
import { Team, getTeamsAsync, selectProgress, updateTeamAsync } from "../../../../redux/features/teams/teamsSlice";
import {
  Box,
  Button,
  CircularProgress,
  FormControlLabel,
  FormLabel,
  Modal,
  Stack,
  Switch,
  TextField,
  Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import { Controller, useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

interface Props {
  open: boolean;
  handleClose: () => void;
  team: Team | undefined;
}

const TeamUpdateModal: FC<Props> = ({ open, handleClose, team }) => {
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const { teamId } = useParams();
  const isProgress = useAppSelector<boolean>(selectProgress);
  const {
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    formState: { isValid, errors },
    register,
  } = useForm();

  const style = {
    position: "absolute",
    top: "50%",
    left: "50%",
    transform: "translate(-50%, -50%)",
    width: 400,
    bgcolor: "background.paper",
    border: "2px solid #000",
    boxShadow: 24,
    pt: 2,
    px: 4,
    pb: 3,
  };

  const onCancel = () => {
    handleClose();
  };

  const updateTeam = handleSubmit(async (data) => {
    if (!isValid) return;
    if (teamId != undefined) {
      const result = await dispatch(
        updateTeamAsync({
          teamId,
          teamName: data["teamName"],
          companyName: data["companyName"],
        })
      );
    }
  });

  return (
    <Modal
      open={open}
      onClose={() => handleClose()}
      aria-labelledby="update-team-modal"
      aria-describedby="update modal for team setting"
    >
      <Box sx={{ ...style, width: 800 }}>
        <Typography sx={{ mt: 2, mb: 2, fontWeight: "bold", fontSize: "20px" }}>Team Update</Typography>
        <form onSubmit={updateTeam}>
          <Stack spacing={3}>
            <Controller
              name="companyName"
              control={control}
              defaultValue={team?.companyName || ""}
              render={(): JSX.Element => {
                return (
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="Company Name *"
                    error={!!errors["companyName"]}
                    InputProps={{
                      inputProps: { maxLength: 50 },
                    }}
                    sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                    {...register("companyName", {
                      required: "required",
                      maxLength: 50,
                    })}
                    autoComplete="true"
                    helperText={errors["companyName"]?.message}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
            <Controller
              name="teamName"
              control={control}
              defaultValue={team?.teamName || ""}
              render={(): JSX.Element => {
                return (
                  <TextField
                    variant="outlined"
                    label="Team Name *"
                    error={!!errors["teamName"]}
                    sx={{ width: "100%" }}
                    InputProps={{
                      inputProps: { maxLength: 50 },
                    }}
                    {...register("teamName", {
                      required: "required",
                      maxLength: 50,
                    })}
                    autoComplete="true"
                    helperText={errors["teamName"]?.message}
                  />
                );
              }}
            />
             <Stack direction="row" marginTop={5} justifyContent="flex-end" spacing={3}>
              <Button type="submit" disabled={isProgress}>
                {isProgress ? <CircularProgress /> : "SUBMIT"}
              </Button>
              <Button onClick={onCancel}>CANCEL</Button>
            </Stack>
          </Stack>
        </form>
      </Box>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default TeamUpdateModal;
```

TeamUpdateModal.test.tsx

```
import { act, fireEvent, render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
import React from "react";
import TeamRegistrationModal from "./TeamRegistrationModal";

const mockDispatch = jest.fn();

const mockCreateTeamAsync = jest.fn();
const mockSelectProgress = jest.fn();
const mockHandleClose = jest.fn();

jest.mock("../../../../redux/hooks", () => ({
  useAppDispatch: () => mockDispatch,
  useAppSelector: (arg: () => void) => {
    if (arg.name === "selectProgress") false;
    return arg();
  },
}));

jest.mock("../../../../redux/features/teams/teamsSlice", () => ({
  __esModule: true,
  ...jest.requireActual("../../../../redux/features/teams/teamsSlice"),
  createTeamAsync: (payload: {
    teamName: string;
    companyName: string;
  }) => mockCreateTeamAsync(payload),
  selectProgress: () => mockSelectProgress(),
}));

describe("TeamRegistrationModal", () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockCreateTeamAsync.mockClear();
    mockSelectProgress.mockClear();
    mockHandleClose.mockClear();
  });
  test("Input is submitted successfully", async () => {
    act(() => {
      render(<TeamRegistrationModal open={true} handleClose={mockHandleClose} />);
    });

    const teamNameInput = screen.getByLabelText("Team Name *", { selector: "input" }) as HTMLInputElement;
    const companyNameInput = screen.getByLabelText("Company Name *", { selector: "input" }) as HTMLInputElement;

    fireEvent.input(teamNameInput, { target: { value: "username" } });
    fireEvent.input(companyNameInput, { target: { value: "company" } });


    const button = screen.getByText("SUBMIT");

    fireEvent.click(button);

    expect(mockCreateTeamAsync).toBeCalledTimes(1); <= error occurs 
  });
});
```

I inserted useForm mode as onBlur, but error is not removed.